# AES vs PBEWithSHA256And256BitAES

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes

I need to encrypt some data with a password. It has to be a variation of AES with a 256bit key.
I searched a while on the web and came up with this two alogrithms. Now I do not know, which one to choose, cause I do not know, which one is 'saver'.

The first one is the PBEWithSHA256And256BitAES-CBC-BC:

```
public static byte[] encrypt(String plainText, char[] password, byte[] salt) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchProviderException {
    PBEParameterSpec pbeParamSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, 2048);

    PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password);
    SecretKeyFactory keyFac = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithSHA256And256BitAES-CBC-BC", "BC");
    SecretKey pbeKey = keyFac.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);

    Cipher encryptionCipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithSHA256And256BitAES-CBC-BC", "BC");
    encryptionCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, pbeParamSpec);

    return encryptionCipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes());
}
```

The other one generates the Key with PBEWithSHA256And256BitAES-CBC-BC, but encrypts with AES:

```
public static byte[] encrypt(String plainText, char[] password, byte[] salt) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchProviderException {
    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithSHA256And256BitAES-CBC-BC", "BC");
    KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, 2048, 256);
    SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(factory.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded(), "AES");

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    return cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes());
}
```

So, which one - and why - is the more secure one? And what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should certainly specify a mode of operation for your block cipher. That's the "CBC" part of cipher in the BC implementation.  Otherwise, you will default to ECB mode, which has simple codebook replay attack possible!  So, long story short - don't use the bottom code snip, prefer the top one.

It could be fixed up to operate similar to how the BC implementation does by specifying mode of operation and other parameters - but honestly just use the BC if you don't know about this stuff - they've done the work and those providers are ready to use as you want "out of the box".

Comment: What if I use "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding" or "AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding" instead?

Comment: Either would use CBC and avoid the attack I mention.  I'd really have to know the about the BC implementation (specifically what sort of PBE key expansion it is doing) to compare those with it a whole lot more, tho...  Your best bet is probably to stick with BC.

Comment: @Ph3n1x pkcs5 and pkcs7 paddings are the same thing for AES: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9043/what-is-the-difference-between-pkcs5-padding-and-pkcs7-padding